# How to set barcod output format in jasperreports?

Tags: jasper-reports, barcode

I try to create a barcode and export it to DOCX. But when I open this DOCX, the image resolution of the barcode is very bad.
I have read, that Barcode4j supports multiple output formats (SVG, EPS, Bitmap images, ...), but how can I set it?

My test code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.1  -->
<!-- 2016-04-30T14:14:48 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="folder" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="495" leftMargin="50" rightMargin="50" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isTitleNewPage="true" uuid="6dc4b54d-6b32-4fd1-ad46-f29c5a32288e">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <title>
        <band height="171">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="20" width="500" height="140" uuid="e6d94a1f-7df2-4ff2-b836-bb7bb8a106c0">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:EAN13 xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA["123456789012"]]></jr:codeExpression>
                </jr:EAN13>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Eventually, how can I create DOCX with high image resolution of a barcode?

Comment: P.S. Export to PDF is working  good

Comment: It seems that if you use direct Java code you can provide a canvas, e.g. SVG. In the report only a bitmap canvas is provided. Maybe you can render the image at a higher resolution and then scale the image down?

Comment: I have tried to scale, but I could not. I used export to PDF.